# Racket, stepper, I dont understand one thing

Tags: racket

```
(let ((+ *) (* +))
  (+ 3 (* 4 5)))
```

Stepper outs something as:

```
(define +_0 *)
(define *_0 +)
(+_0 3 (*_0 4 5))
```

Everything is clear but I why does occur +_0? On my eye it should be:

```
(define + *)
(define * +)
(+_0 3 (* 4 5))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`define` isn't exactly the same as `let`. In a `let` the values are evaluated before the binding occurs while with `define` it gets binded to an undefined value and it shadows the original procedures. The expansion makes sure the variables do not shadow the values they are set to by using other symbols in the form.

Try running these:

```
(let ()
  (define + *)
  (define * +) 
  (+ 3 (* 4 5))) ; * and + are undefined so this will fail

(let ()
  (define + *)
  (define * +) 
  (list + *))  ; ==> (#<undefined> #<undefined>)
```

A let `(let ((x 10)(* +)) (* x x)) ; ==> 20` should evaluate the same as `((lambda (x *) (* x x)) 10 +)` and with this last one you see `10` and `+` are getting evaluated before they are assigned to `x` and `*` inside the procedure.